# delay subscribe popup jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, delay

how i can delay this subscribe popup for 10 seconds? i don't understand where is the mistake.. i tried different codes

```
    <?php
    if ($this->isActivePopUp() && !Mage::helper('newssubscribers')->isMobile()):
    ?>


<script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function() {

        var delay = 10000; // milliseconds
        }
        });

        <?php if (is_numeric($this->getCookieLifeTime())): ?>
        EsNewsSubscribers.setCookieLiveTime(<?php echo $this->getCookieLifeTime(); ?>);
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($this->getCookieName()): ?>
        EsNewsSubscribers.setCookieName('<?php echo $this->getCookieName(); ?>');
        <?php endif; ?>
        EsNewsSubscribers.setBaseUrl('<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl(); ?>');

</script>
    <div id="esns_background_layer">example</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
       setTimeout("startSubscription()",10000);
    }
    });

    function startSubscription()
    {
        <?php if (is_numeric($this->getCookieLifeTime())): ?>
        EsNewsSubscribers.setCookieLiveTime(<?php echo $this->getCookieLifeTime(); ?>);
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($this->getCookieName()): ?>
        EsNewsSubscribers.setCookieName('<?php echo $this->getCookieName(); ?>');
        <?php endif; ?>
        EsNewsSubscribers.setBaseUrl('<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl(); ?>');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: no..it doesn't work. i modify the code. the site: poderelemelie.it

Comment: You just were trying to delay an action in your Javascript code, it doesnt works by creating a "delay" variable, just try to delay that action with a function like setTimeout.